# Unable to upgrade Windows 10 edition from Home to Pro

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, product-key

I have a Lenovo laptop which upgraded from Windows 8.1 Home to Windows 10 Home.

I have a (legitimate) Windows 10 Pro key which I ran through the "Change Product Key" wizard.

After a reboot I get an error which states "We couldn't upgrade your edition" and asks me to try again or seek help from my system administrator (me!) or Microsoft.

There is nothing in the event logs except Info entries in the Setup log stating it failed to change the installed state to Pro Edition with a hex error code (I don't have access to the laptop right now, I will update later with the full log details)

Googling the hex error code led me to a Windows 7 KB Article regarding Windows Update failure due to locked files. The article stepped through using MSCONFIG to perform a clean boot which I did, but still got the error.

Any pointers on how to upgrade this laptop? Or will I have to get the sledgehammer out and do a clean install?

Comment: Which key is the 10 pro key? If it's an OEM key, you can't use for upgrades

Comment: It's a retail key (from MSDN)

Comment: maybe they want an upgrade key? (the "home to pro" key sold in stores for around $59)

Comment: The wizard accepts the key. It fails after a reboot.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had exactly this problem.

I solved it buy obtaining a new Windows 10 Home key from msdn and then changing the product key (also via the settings-> Activation window). After doing this I then repeating the attempt to update to Pro (with legit key) via the store.

My guess is that whatever I had as a key was not eligable for the upgrade combination i was trying via the store.

Comment: I'll try it tonight.

Comment: I finally got round to trying this - it worked!

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I received this error message right after entering the Pro Generic Key `VK7JG-NPHTM-C97JM-9MPGT-3V66T`:

> Unable to upgrade your edition
>
> We can't upgrade your edition of Windows. Try upgrading your edition of Windows again.
> (0x80310000)

This problem occurred to me two times for different reasons with different error codes and with different solutions:

1. In the first case disabling the network connection by enabling the flight mode of my laptop solved the problem.

   I found this solution at Lincoln IT Solutions [Upgrading Windows 10 Home to Windows 10 Pro – Error Code 0x803fa067](http://www.lincolnitsolutions.co.uk/blog/index.php/upgrading-windows-10-home-to-windows-10-pro-error-code-0x803fa067/).
2. In the second case I could solve this by suspending Bitlocker encryption.

   The problem reoccurred when I was upgrading my system which I had installed to another partition, while I had encrypted the system at the first partition with Bitlocker. As explained in [How can I fix error code 0x80310000 for windows 10 mobile update?](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/how-can-i-fix-error-code-0x80310000-for-windows-10/c288209c-ee4d-413e-bf9d-1e56b5c8f6e6) the Bitlocker encryption was the problem and the upgrade worked after suspending it for the other system.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue when trying to upgrade a newly purchased PC from Home to Pro edition.  I tried to swap the original OEM key with another Home key, and still couldn't do the switch to Pro afterwards.

The solution for me was to uninstall the virus checking software that came pre-installed with the PC.  It appears that an active virus checker can prevent the upgrade process from Home to Pro to complete.   Once uninstalled, everything worked flawlessly.

Comment: Wouldn't deactivating the A/V software be enough (so it isn't actively scanning during upgrade), rather than uninstalling it?

Comment: I also state in the question that I clean booted using MSCONFIG which switches off A/V

Answer (score -1):

Since you have legitimate key for windows 10 pro then why you did update to windows 10 home? You can do a clean install with that key.

I suggest to try clean install and see if that key works or not. Since key is checked at early stage, you don't need to worry about your data, formatting partition... etc.

Comment: I wanted to try and avoid a clean install. It had 8.1 Home on it so it got updated to 10 Home. It appears that some features that were supported in 8.1 Home are not in 10 Home (specifically RDP access via WHS 2011) so I now need to change it to Pro. The key is fine, it's an MSDN retail key and it is checked as the first step of the "Change Product Key" process

Comment: not a solution, if you want to have RDP access you can circumvent it with RDPWrapper (never tried via WHS)

Answer (score -2):

Here is what worked for me:

1. uninstall anti-virus software in your machine
2. go to Settings -> Update & Security -> Activation
3. Change product key
4. Enter "Windows 10 Pro" product key from MSDN
5. Click "Start Upgrade"
6. Your machine will reboot and configure updates required for upgrade from Windows 10 Home to Windows 10 Pro

Comment: This is just a repeat of the other two answers.

Comment: I also state in the question that I clean booted using MSCONFIG which switches off A/V

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.