# Windows 8.1 Pro wants to upgrade to 10 Home

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-10, upgrade

I recently bought a new Acer laptop, that had Windows 10 Home preinstalled. Since I still had a Windows 8 Pro key, I wanted to upgrade that to 10 Pro.

What I did so far:

- Install Windows 8.1 using a generic key (as the installer didn't accept the Win8 key)
- Enter the Windows 8 key and activate license
- Using MediaCreationTool I created a bootable Windows 10 USB drive
- As suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1020961/prevent-windows-10-installer-from-using-the-preinstalled-serial-key-without-disa) I created `PID.txt` inside the `Sources` folder, that contains my original Windows 8 key I used to activate 8.1
- When booting from the USB drive and choosing to upgrade Windows, I get the following notice:

  Compatibility report

  The computer started using WIndows installation media. Remove the installation media and restart your computer so that Windows starts normally. Then, insert the installation media and restart the upgrade.
- However, when restarting the upgrade after booting Windows, it wants to install Windows 10 Home

So what else can I try, to upgrade to 10 Pro?

Comment: Is the Windows 8 Pro key an OEM version?

Comment: "Install Windows 8.1 using a generic key" what is a generic key?

Comment: See this.....http://superuser.com/questions/1020961/prevent-windows-10-installer-from-using-the-preinstalled-serial-key-without-disa

Comment: @TechKno no, I got it via MSDN-AA.

Comment: a generic key allows you only to install windows. to activate you still need a valid key.

Comment: The proper way to do this type of upgrade is to install Windows 10 Home then use the upgrade mechanic to upgrade to Windows 10 Professional.  It has [worked](http://superuser.com/questions/950350/unable-to-upgrade-windows-10-edition-from-home-to-pro?rq=1) for people in the past.

Comment: In the future if you ask this question, before you go down the path you believe is correct, we can help you avoid necessary steps.

Answer (score 2):

You can upgrade to Windows 10 Pro from Windows 10 Home using a Windows 7 or 8/8.1 Pro key.

First you need to upgrade to Windows 10 Home. Then Go to Settings > Update & Security > Activation > Change Product Key, then type VK7JG-NPHTM-C97JM-9MPGT-3V66T as the product key.

This will activate Windows 10 Pro but it will not be acivated and you won't have access to some of the features. Do this again, but instead of entering in the other key, enter in your Windows 8.1 key, then you will have activated Windows 10 Pro!

For more info on how to do this, visit [this guide](http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/windows-10-pro-default-product-key/).